# Unable to install any package using Pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Whenever I run the command `pip install Django` I get the following error trace which means there is some version conflict. I tried uninstalling and then installing the same package, but it's throwing up the same error.

```
Downloading/unpacking bcrypt (from Django)
  Downloading bcrypt-2.0.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/bcrypt/setup.py) egg_info for package bcrypt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/bcrypt/setup.py", line 226, in <module>
        **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options
        ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in require
        working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 592, in resolve
        raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
    pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (certifi 2016.2.28 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('certifi==2015.11.20'))
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/bcrypt/setup.py", line 226, in <module>

    **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__

    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options

    ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in require

    working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 592, in resolve

    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here

pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (certifi 2016.2.28 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('certifi==2015.11.20'))

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
```

I am using Python 2.7. Anybody knows what is the issue?

Comment: I did it. Still the same error

Comment: Can you try `pip install certifi==2015.11.20` then?

Comment: I did that. Now, I am getting a different error:   

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1290, in _setup_prefix

    while path!=old:

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...

Comment: "any package" seems broad considering you've only shown the error message of one `bcrypt` package

Comment: @cricket_007 But the error is caused by `distribute` which is part of `setuptools`, so it might be true that every installation gives the same error.

Comment: @Abhijay Can you try `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: @Selcuk Is it because I don't have Python3?

Comment: @Selcuk I am getting the same error as the one in my original question. VersionConflict: (certifi 2016.2.28 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('certifi==2015.11.20'))

Comment: check this answer    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Comment: @Abhijay  did you made any  progress on issue

Comment: @SayedZainulAbideen I setup a virtualenv and got it to work. However, the issue has still not been resolved

Comment: @Abhijay  what about manually downloading and installing certifi

Answer (score 2):

It seems like all the problem is because of `certifi` version conflict

so try downloading the source from here
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

and install from source

Extract it go into the folder and run this command

```
sudo python setup.py  install
```

and it should work

peace

Answer (score 0):

I met such a situation when I had already used system package manager like aptitude or pacman to install that very package, or dependency package
(they, pip and system package manager, do not know each other, while they install package at the same folder, some site-package thing, so it's easy to get a file already exist like problem)

You need to see which is conflict, open your python console, try to import it, and see where is it with module_name.**file**, remove it(or the folder) manually (please backup before problem really solved).

Or just use pip and system package manager to verify which has been already installed